# readline set_completion_display_matches_hook requires return key before displaying prompt

Tags: python, readline

**Background**

Hi I am trying to write a custom display for my tab completion output in readline. Here is my `display hook` function-

**Code**

```
def match_display_hook(self, substitution, matches, longest_match_length):
    print ''
    for match in matches:
        print match
    readline.redisplay()
```

**Question**

But the problem is that I have to press the return key to get a prompt unlike the default tab completion output where I can get the prompt right away. I see `rl` module has been suggested by someone in another thread, but is there no way to get it done through readline itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay i found a way, not sure if this is the right way to fix it. But i printed the prompt and readline buffer at the end of the match_display_hook and all seems well and good. Here is my new match_display_hook:

```
def match_display_hook(self, substitution, matches, longest_match_length):
    print ''
    for match in matches:
        print match
    print self.prompt.rstrip(),
    print readline.get_line_buffer(),
    readline.redisplay()
```

This works well.

Comment: Works for me on OSX 10.9.5