# Python : correct use of set_completion_display_matches_hook

Tags: python, python-3.x, readline

I'm trying to write a function to display a custom view when users press the tab button. Apparently "set_completion_display_matches_hook" function is what I need, I can display a custom view, but the problem is that I have to press Enter to get a prompt again.

The solution in Python2 seems to be that ([solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148768/readline-set-completion-display-matches-hook-requires-return-key-before-displayi)):

```
def match_display_hook(self, substitution, matches, longest_match_length):
    print ''
    for match in matches:
        print match
    print self.prompt.rstrip(),
    print readline.get_line_buffer(),
    readline.redisplay()
```

But it doesn't work with Python3. I made these syntax changes :

```
def match_display_hook(self, substitution, matches, longest_match_length):
        print('\n----------------------------------------------\n')
        for match in matches:
            print(match)
        print(self.prompt.rstrip() + readline.get_line_buffer())
        readline.redisplay()
```

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the Python 2 code uses commas to leave the line unfinished. In Python 3, it's done using `end` keyword:

```
print(self.prompt.rstrip(), readline.get_line_buffer(), sep='', end='')
```

Then, a flush is required to actually display the unfinished line (due to line buffering):

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

The `redisplay()` call does not seem to be needed.

The final code:

```
def match_display_hook(self, substitution, matches, longest_match_length):
    print()
    for match in matches:
        print(match)
    print(self.prompt.rstrip(), readline.get_line_buffer(), sep='', end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `redisplay()` function

> `void`[`rl_redisplay (void)`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC35)
>   Change what's displayed on the screen to reflect the current contents of [rl_line_buffer](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#IDX215).

In your example you have written to `stdout`, but not changed that buffer.

Print and flush as described by in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37712990/3342816) should work.

One issue you will have, however, is cursor position. Say you have this scenario:

```
$ cmd   some_file
      ^
      +---- User has back-tracked here and want to insert an option.
            <TAB> completion with print and flush will put cursor
            at end of `some_file' and the line will get an extra 15
            spaces after that ...
```

To remedy this one way is to first get cursor position, then use ANSI sequences to re-position the cursor.

```
buf = readline.get_line_buffer()
x = readline.get_endidx()

print(self.prompt + buf, end = '')

if x < len(buf):
    """ Set cursor at old column position """
    print("\r\033[%dC" % (x + len(self.prompt)), end = '')

sys.stdout.flush()
```

Now, of course, you get another issue if `prompt` has ANSI sequences in-iteself. Typically color or the like. Then you can not use `len(prompt)` but have to find printed / visible length.

One has to use open and close bytes elsewhere, typically `\0x01` and `\0x02` respectively.

So one typically get:

```
prompt = '\001\033[31;1m\002VISIBLE_TEXT\001\033[0m\002 '
```

instead of:

```
prompt = '\033[31;1mVISIBLE_TEXT\033[0m '
```

With those guards it should be easy enough to strip out the visible text.

Typically something like:

```
clean_prompt = re.sub(r'\001[^\002]*\002', '', prompt))
```

Cache the length of that and use when printing the readline manually. Note that you also have to remove the guards when using it manually - as in the hook function. (But it is needed in `input(prompt)`

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me for redisplaying substitution and the end of matches display for python3:

```
    def match_display_hook(self, substitution, matches, longest_match_length):
        print("")
        for match in matches:
            print(match)
        print("")
        sys.stdout.write(substitution)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        return None
```

while previous ones using print prompt didn't. (didn't get to the bottom of the problem)